# how to call soap based web service in phone gap

Tags: cordova

can you please give me another way to call soap based web service . recently i used this example ..
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12816/JavaScript-SOAP-Client

But problem is that i am not using ASP.net or.i am using for phone gap .problem is that when i debug this in firefox it show wsdl is null or wsdl is undefined .but when i run same program in IE it will work fine.the problem is that in future if i want to debug the js, i am not able to do that .so i need another way to call soap client web service.

one again i will tell you i am not using for asp.net i am using for phonegap technology
can you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

This probably doesn't answer the OP's question, but might be useful for anyone else using the Javascript SOAP Client from [CodePlex](http://javascriptsoapclient.codeplex.com) who gets the "wsdl is null" error.

I simply had the wrong URL to my ASMX file!